django-allauth cant select providers using administration page
I'm trying to add google authentication to my django application that is a social network, I added 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google' into installed apps and created
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    },
}

But administration page doesnt show me this provider
no option to select google
Having followed all the required steps in the docs, obtained client id and secret key e and I also have refreshed, cleared cache, run makemigrations and migrate many times but the field won't show 'google' as the option. Could you show me the way to solve this? Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There was a mistake by me, I thought that I installed django-allauth[socialaccount], but I didn't, that fixed the problem.
Sorry for bothering you, I hope this answer will help someone)
